# Why no link in the header of the main site to our 'About' page?

Tags: feature-request

On the main site, we have a lovely new [About page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/about). Five of us have found it (it's linked from the footer of the main site) and read it, and so got the [Informed Badge](https://academia.stackexchange.com/badges/89/informed)

All the other sites I've seen, have "about" linked in the top header on the main site. But Academia does not.

Please can we have an About link in the header of the main site?

Comment: Hmm - I have an about link in the header of the main site in my browser (Chrome), can you post a screen shot where it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just asked some other mods about this, and I learned that apparently that link disappears when you pass 2k in beta sites, and 5k on graduated sites. See [this post for the relevant discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72043/139256).