# Is it ethical to promote another Stack Exchange website in about me section of the users' profiles?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I like one or two other Stack Exchange websites but they have really low user participation. I want to promote those websites by mentioning their names with a link in my User's Profile about me section. I have seen some users doing this on our site on their profiles.

Is it ethical to do such thing? Doesn't it conflict Academia's website policies?

related question, but not a duplicate: [Why no link in the header of the main site to our 'About' page?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/why-no-link-in-the-header-of-the-main-site-to-our-about-page)

Comment: You might get a better response if we migrate this to the main meta. Is there a reason you want to limit the question only to AC.SE?

Comment: @StrongBad Not any special reason. Just because the Academia is the website I visit more often. However, I am not sure there is not any duplicate questions there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

Answer (score 6):

To me, the question is this: where is the line between appropriate promotion and spam / single-purpose-accounts?  I have noticed that when an account is *centered* on a link in its user profile, that can be considered evidence of inappropriate promotion.  If the promotion is just a small part of an otherwise well-rounded account, however, I see no issue at all.  For example, in your own case, you are a well-established contributor to this site who is known for doing a lot of different constructive work.  Adding clear, transparent lines in your profile that say, "I like this stuff, and think you should check it out too" seems to me to be no problem at all.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it ethical to promote another Stack Exchange website in about me section of the users' profiles?

It doesn't trigger an ethical question. It's fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my question. Could you please expand your negative answer a little more and give some reasoning why you think it is unethical to put another Stack Exchange website's link in the user's profile section to promote them and to increase their visitors?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I think you misinterpreted the answer. The answer, at least to my reading is that there is no reason to think it is unethical, or without the double negative, there is every reason to think it is ethical.

Answer (score 1):

Wow why would it be unethical are you selling something?